I2S clock provider mode not supported - How to enable?
Introduktion:
I having a HDMI PHY SII9022A. I want to enable audio on that PHY.
Requriments:
I need to create a proper device tree for the SII9022A.
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/display/bridge/sil%2Csii9022.yaml
According to this file, I need to activate audio-graph-card bindings and of course i2s.
I have created my device tree. Notice that I have not using MCLK (Master Clock) because PLL can be used instead of MCLK.


My linux kernel configuration looks like this.

My device tree looks like this:
hdmi-transmitter@39{
    compatible = "sil,sii9022";
    reg = <0x39>;
    iovcc-supply = <&v3v3_hdmi>;
    cvcc12-supply = <&v1v2_hdmi>;
    reset-gpios = <&gpioe 8 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
    interrupts = <1 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING>;
    interrupt-parent = <&gpiog>;
    #sound-dai-cells = <0>;
    sil,i2s-data-lanes = <0>;
    /*clocks = <&mclk>;
    clock-names = "mclk";*/
    status = "okay";

    ports{
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        port@0{
            reg = <0>;

            sii9022_in:endpoint{
                remote-endpoint = <&ltdc_ep0_out>;
            };
        };

        port@1{
            reg = <1>;

            sii9022_out:endpoint{
                remote-endpoint = <&hdmi_connector_in>;
            };
        };

        port@3{
            reg = <3>;

            sii9022_tx_endpoint:endpoint{
                remote-endpoint = <&i2s2_endpoint>;
            };
        };
    };
};

&i2s2{
    pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep";
    pinctrl-0 = <&i2s2_pins_mx>;
    pinctrl-1 = <&i2s2_sleep_pins_mx>;
    status = "okay";

    /* USER CODE BEGIN i2s2 */
    clocks = <&rcc SPI2>, <&rcc SPI2_K>, <&rcc PLL3_Q>, <&rcc PLL3_R>;
    clock-names = "pclk", "i2sclk", "x8k", "x11k";

    i2s2_port:port{
        i2s2_endpoint:endpoint{
            remote-endpoint = <&sii9022_tx_endpoint>;
            dai-format = "i2s";
            mclk-fs = <256>;
        };
    };
    /* USER CODE END i2s2 */
};

Question:
As you can see, I'm using the dai-format = "i2s", but still, I'm getting this debug messages.
drivers/gpu/drm/bridge/sii902x.c:577 [sii902x]sii902x_audio_hw_params =p "%s: Unsupported i2s format %u\n"
drivers/gpu/drm/bridge/sii902x.c:560 [sii902x]sii902x_audio_hw_params =p "%s: I2S clock provider mode not supported\n"

From this .c code: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/gpu/drm/bridge/sii902x.c
static int sii902x_audio_hw_params(struct device *dev, void *data,
                   struct hdmi_codec_daifmt *daifmt,
                   struct hdmi_codec_params *params)
{
    struct sii902x *sii902x = dev_get_drvdata(dev);
    u8 i2s_config_reg = SII902X_TPI_I2S_SD_DIRECTION_MSB_FIRST;
    u8 config_byte2_reg = (SII902X_TPI_AUDIO_INTERFACE_I2S |
                   SII902X_TPI_AUDIO_MUTE_ENABLE |
                   SII902X_TPI_AUDIO_CODING_PCM);
    u8 config_byte3_reg = 0;
    u8 infoframe_buf[HDMI_INFOFRAME_SIZE(AUDIO)];
    unsigned long mclk_rate;
    int i, ret;

    if (daifmt->bit_clk_provider || daifmt->frame_clk_provider) {
        dev_dbg(dev, "%s: I2S clock provider mode not supported\n", __func__); <--------------------------
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    switch (daifmt->fmt) {
    case HDMI_I2S:
        i2s_config_reg |= SII902X_TPI_I2S_FIRST_BIT_SHIFT_YES |
            SII902X_TPI_I2S_SD_JUSTIFY_LEFT;
        break;
    case HDMI_RIGHT_J:
        i2s_config_reg |= SII902X_TPI_I2S_SD_JUSTIFY_RIGHT;
        break;
    case HDMI_LEFT_J:
        i2s_config_reg |= SII902X_TPI_I2S_SD_JUSTIFY_LEFT;
        break;
    default:
        dev_dbg(dev, "%s: Unsupported i2s format %u\n", __func__, daifmt->fmt); <--------------------------------
        return -EINVAL;
    }

So how can I get the I2S clock prover mode a proper setup?

Here is the answer:
Make sure that you are given dailink0_master to the CPU and not the codec itself.
sound {
    compatible = "simple-audio-card";
    simple-audio-card,name = "SII9022A HDMI";
    simple-audio-card,format = "i2s";
    /*simple-audio-card,widgets = "Speaker", "External Speaker";
    simple-audio-card,routing = "External Speaker", "LINE_OUT";*/
    simple-audio-card,bitclock-master = <&dailink0_master>;
    simple-audio-card,frame-master = <&dailink0_master>;
    simple-audio-card,mclk-fs = <256>;
    
    dailink0_master: simple-audio-card,cpu {
        sound-dai = <&i2s2>;
    };
    
    simple-audio-card,codec {
        sound-dai = <&sii9022A>;
    };
};

